# Checkbox check selection in MVC Razor table is coming as false

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have below table -

```
   <tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
   {
    <tr>
        <td>                    
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ShouldImport, new { @class = "sid", @onclick = "DisplayDetailedInfo(this)" })               
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Name)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AccountNumber)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AccountNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AccountType)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AccountType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AccountStatus)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AccountStatus)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].IsLatePayment)
        </td>           
    </tr>
}
```

My Javascript Function is follows -

```
function DisplayDetailedInfo(data) {
console.log(data);
var vval = $(data).val();
var anotherval = $(this).is(':checked')
console.log(anotherval);
if (anotherval)
{
    console.log("Hi");
}
}
```

I need assistance why I am getting value as false although I am checking the Checkbox. I am new to razor and Jquery and need assistance.

Comment: `$(this)` is undefined within your function. You're passing `this` to function as `data` var. So you should do `$(data).is(':checked')`

Comment: You will find this easier using [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) - `$('.sid').click(function() { console.log($(this).is(':checked')); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `this` in your case is returning `window` so you have to replace it with `data` as follows:

```
function DisplayDetailedInfo(data) {
   console.log(data);
   var vval = $(data).val();
   var anotherval = $(data).is(':checked');
   console.log(anotherval);
   if (anotherval)
   {
      console.log("Hi");
   }
}
```